# jquery-ui datepicker: multiple input box mirroring

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have 2 sets of input boxes:

1) "Start Date I" and "End Date I"

2) "Start Date II" and "End Date II"

as it can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/YXzpj/

What I need is that whenever user sets the start and end dates of one side, chosen values should be copied to the other side.

For example:
User sets "Start Date I" and then "End Date I", then the script should automatically copy both values to "Start Date II" and "End Date II". If user changes any of the four fields, the form should update itself accordingly. In other words, these two sets of input boxes should mirror each other.

Here is my current code:

```
$(function() {

    var currentTime = new Date();


    $('#report2from1').attr('readonly','readonly');
    $('#report2to1').attr('readonly','readonly');    
    var dates1 = $( "#report2from1, #report2to1" ).datepicker({
        showButtonPanel: true,            
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        minDate: new Date(2010, 1 -1, 1),
        maxDate: new Date(currentTime.getFullYear(), 11, 31),
        dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            var option = this.id == "report2from1" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
                date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                    instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                    $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                    selectedDate, instance.settings );
            dates1.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
            if ( this.id == "report2from1" ){
                dates1.not( this ).datepicker( "setDate", date );
            }
        }
    });    

    $('#report2from2').attr('readonly','readonly');
    $('#report2to2').attr('readonly','readonly');
    var dates2 = $( "#report2from2, #report2to2" ).datepicker({
        showButtonPanel: true,    
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        minDate: new Date(2010, 1 -1, 1),
        maxDate: new Date(currentTime.getFullYear(), 11, 31),
        dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            var option = this.id == "report2from2" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
                date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                    instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                    $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                    selectedDate, instance.settings );
            dates2.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
            if ( this.id == "report2from2" ){
                dates2.not( this ).datepicker( "setDate", date );
            }                
        }
    });


});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Datepicker plugin has an option to do automatically what you are looking: [altField](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-altField)

> **altField**
>   *Selector, jQuery, ElementDefault:''*
>   The jQuery selector for another field that is to be updated with the selected date from the datepicker. Use the altFormat setting to change the format of the date within this field. Leave as blank for no alternate field.

Here's how I would optimize your code:

```
$(function() {

    var currentTime = new Date(),
        // cache your selection already
        $dateFields = $('#report2from1, #report2to1, #report2from2, #report2to2');

    // set all fields to readonly
    $dateFields.attr('readonly', 'readonly');

    // the options are the same for all instances
    var options = {
        showButtonPanel: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        minDate: new Date(2010, 1 - 1, 1),
        maxDate: new Date(currentTime.getFullYear(), 11, 31),
        dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
        // set the date on open so the populated date is selected in the widget
        beforeShow: function(input, instance) {
            $(input).datepicker('setDate', $(input).val());
        }
    };

    // instanciate datepicker with the options for all the fields
    $dateFields.datepicker(options);

    // apply separately the option 'altField' accordingly
    $('#report2from1').datepicker('option', 'altField', '#report2from2');
    $('#report2from2').datepicker('option', 'altField', '#report2from1');
    $('#report2to1').datepicker('option', 'altField', '#report2to2');
    $('#report2to2').datepicker('option', 'altField', '#report2to1');

});​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/vBmY2/)**

Comment: btw. I've just noticed that this demo does not respect the min and max values which mean that the end date can be chosen a date before the start date. How can you fix that?